# Displaying values (from a subclass) of an object in an ArrayList (based off the superclass)

Tags: java, class, inheritance, arraylist

I have 3 classes:

1. Sportswear (superclass)
2. Jersey (subclass)
3. Driver

I have an `ArrayList` in my driver to hold all my jerseys created. I input and store values into a jersey object `(stock, price, product, team, kit, size, gender)`.

stock, price, product are processed in the superclass (Sportswear) and
team, kit, size, gender are processed in the subclass (Jersey).

I want to display all Jerseys with all their details, for example:

```
Product 1:
**********
Product: Jersey
In stock: 50
Price: €35.0
Team: Manchester United
Kit: Home
Size: M
Gender: Male

Product 2:
**********
Product: Jersey
In stock: 70
Price: €25.99
Team: liverpool
Kit: Away
Size: L
Gender: Female
```

and so on...

the arrayList is `sportswear`

I don't know what to write in the `for loop`. This doesn't work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sportswear.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Product "+(i+1)+": "+sportswear.get(i).jerseyDisplay());
        }
```

The `jerseyDisplay()` method in the subclass Jersey:

```
public void jerseyDisplay()
    {
        super.sportswearDisplay();

        System.out.println("Team: "+team);

        System.out.println("Kit: "+kit);

        System.out.println("Size: "+size);

        System.out.println("Gender: "+gender);
    }
```

The `sportswearDisplay()` method in the superclass (Sportswear):

```
public void sportswearDisplay()
    {
        System.out.println("Product: "+product);
        System.out.println("In stock: "+stock);
        System.out.println("Price: \u20AC"+price);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please say the meaning of `doesn't work` ? with what you get now or the errors?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to override [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in your classes. Did you try it ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it. I'll look it up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The whole beauty of inheritance is that you can provide multiple implementations for a general method. The superclass and indeed any callers of the superclass only need to know the method signature, they do not need to know the exact implementation of the method, as defined in the subclass.

What I'd do is make a `display` method inside the SportsWear class and let Jersey override it. Then you can tell SportsWear to execute the method, and the method inside Jersey will be called.

```
//Inside Sportswear class:

public String display() {
    //todo
}

//Inside Jersey class:

@Override
public String display() {
    super.display();
    //todo
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm now getting an error : `'void' type not allowed here `

At the for loop:
`for(int i = 0; i < sportswear.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Product "+(i+1)+": ");
            System.out.println(sportswear.get(i).display());
            
        }`

Comment: @user636363 How did you implement `display()`? Does it return a String?